# Emit events after non periodic intervals using rx java

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I want to emit events after non periodic intervals and I want to set the interval for emission of each event programatically using Rxjava in Android. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want one of the `Observable.delay` operators that takes a function to specify the delay for each item: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#delay-io.reactivex.functions.Function-